# Should I use indexes for a many-to-many database table?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

does it make sense to create indexes for a table called user_movies with the following columns:

user_id
movie_id

There will be much more reading than inserting or updating on this table but I'm not sure what to do. Also: Is it adequate to omit a primary key in this situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct definition for this table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user_movies (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  movie_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, movie_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(movie_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

Notice "primary key" is a constraint, not a column.  It's best practice to have a primary key *constraint* in every table.  Do not confuse primary key constraint with an auto-generated pseudokey column.

In MySQL, declaring a foreign key or a primary key implicitly creates an index.  Yes, these are beneficial.

Comment: i know this is old but I can't help it: Please use singular noun for table name: e.g. **user** and *not* **users**    ..and all the DBAs rejoyced!

Comment: @dwkd, thanks for the suggestion. You can use your naming convention and I'll use mine. The more important thing about a naming convention is following it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

I would index both columns separately and yes you can eliminate the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I have always heard that you should create a unique index on BOTH columns, first one way (`user_id` + `movie_id`) then the other way (`movie_id` + `user_id`). It DOES work slightly faster (not much, about 10-20%) in my application with some quick and dirty testing.

It also makes sure you can't have two rows that tie the same `movie_id` to the same `user_id` (which could be good, but perhaps not always).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using such a "join-table", you'll probably use some joins in your queries -- and those will probably benefit from an index on each one of those two columns (which means two separate indexes).